# Fantom ERROR: cannot load SWT library;

Tags: java, ide, swt, fantom

I am brand new to Fantom and the IDE F4. I am not sure why, but the IDE is throwing this error whenever I try to run a script. I am positive that I have the right path set up for the SWT Library.

C:\Fantom\fantom-1.0.69\lib\java\ext\win32-x86\swt.jar

```
 ERROR: cannot load SWT library; see http://fantom.org/doc/docTools/Setup.html#swt

 sys::Err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/events/KeyListener: cannot load SWT library; see http://fantom.org/doc/docTools/Setup.html#swt
   fan.sys.FanClassLoader.findClass (FanClassLoader.java:118)
   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (Unknown)
   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (Unknown)
   fwt::Widget.<init> (Widget.fan:27)
   fwt::Pane.<init> (Pane.fan:20)
   fwt::ContentPane.<init> (ContentPane.fan:17)
   fwt::Window.<init> (Window.fan:17)
   fwt::Window.make (Window.fan:139)
   UITest::FwtHello.main (HelloWorld.fan:24)
   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown)
   fan.sys.Method.invoke (Method.java:559)
   fan.sys.Method$MethodFunc.callOn (Method.java:230)
   fan.sys.Method.callOn (Method.java:139)
   fanx.tools.Fan.callMain (Fan.java:185)
   fanx.tools.Fan.executeType (Fan.java:147)
   fanx.tools.Fan.execute (Fan.java:41)
   fanx.tools.Fan.run (Fan.java:308)
   fanx.tools.Fan.main (Fan.java:346)
```

Comment: Did you change the `Env` settings at all? See `Window -> Preferences -> Fantom -> Env`. If in doubt, select `None` to use the default F4 setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled the F4 IDE and everything works fine now. Still unsure what I did to create this issue in the first place.